# c++ - How to limit filetypes through QFileSystemModel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I developed 2 models in Qt Creator. A Treeview and a Listview. I managed to censor out single files from Treeview by `setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files)` so that only folders show up. The content (single files) of the seleceted folder is then shown in my Listview. But i don't know how to only show specific file types from the folder selected, for example I would only like to see image files (.jpg , .png , etc...).

I tried these commands:

```
filemodel->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<".jpg");

filemodel->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.jpg");
```

but all files (even jpg) get shadowed out, which means it doesn't recognize the file type. And .txt files for example still show up in the listview of filemodel. Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: How you are setting root  path?

Comment: @PavanChandaka root path is C: drive, but i have set up a on click button to browse through files which is linked to treeview

Comment: @MohammadKanan yes that exactly what I was looking for and it works, thank you very much :)